# Calling jQuery function from class inside html returned from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use jquery on my page with ajax. I have HTML code returned by ajax call

```
function GetList() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/List.asmx/List1",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                    },
                    contentType: "application/Json; Charset= Utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var list = "";
                        $.each(data.d, function (index, item) {
                            list += '<div itemid=' + item.Nu + ' class="btn btn-default box">' + item.Name + '</div>';
                        });
                        $("#container1").html(list);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
            }
```

and inside this HTML I have a class his name 'box' and this function jquery  to use box

```
$('.box').draggable({
                    cursor: 'move',
                    helper: "clone"
                });
```

the problem this class did not use it by jquery
please, someone, have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean that the new element build in the AJAX success function is not draggable? Probably you have to call draggable again afterwards.

Comment: @Rymo Yes, bro not working

Comment: Do you recall $('#container1 .box').draggable(.....  after AJAX completion? You can do it in the AJAX done function for example.

Comment: @Rymo yes bro thank you it's working

Comment: Your'e welcome, I also added more detailed answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the draggable function only applies on DOM elements and not on dynamically created elements.

You can re-call the draggable function in the AJAX done to solve the problem.

```
function GetList() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/List.asmx/List1",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                },
                contentType: "application/Json; Charset= Utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    var list = "";
                    $.each(data.d, function (index, item) {
                        list += '<div itemid=' + item.Nu + ' class="btn btn-default box">' + item.Name + '</div>';
                    });
                    $("#container1").html(list);
                },
                done: function (response) {
                    $('#container1 .box').draggable({
                        cursor: 'move',
                        helper: "clone"
                    });
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        }
```